# Core-plot Xcode 4 not work on Device

Tags: iphone, xcode4, core-plot

I developing my app with core-plot, and it worked fine before Xcode4. 
Now it only works on iPhone Simulator. And i get a BAD_ACCESS when I load my viewController (wich load my plots).
The BAD_ACCESS is on the following line:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I give you informations about my build settings:

Architecture: Standard(armv6 armv7)

Build active Architecture only:YES

C/C++ compiler version: LLVM GCC 4.2

other linker flags: `-all_load -ObjC`

My header search path is OK (I think, it works on Simulator)

Tell me if you need more informations, or my entire code ^^

thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should then retain your controller.

Comment: wich one? and if you can tell me how. Do I have to set a property to retain the controller?

Comment: You don't have to retain the controller. The `presentModalViewController` does it for you.